# How to find the date a user created their Google account

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I referer this link [Login with Google using PHP API library](https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php) and other tutorial and implement Google Login API in my script.

Once the user has logged in I am looking for how to get the data about when their Google account was created.   I havent been able to find this information in the current login data returned by the oauth server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As in the date the user created their google account?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, the date when user profile has been created

Comment: Why are you looking for this information?

Answer (score 4):

This is a really good question.  To start i know a lot of the Google APIs so I  started digging.   I did check a number of the gmail api end points there was nothing interesting their in my opinion.

**Oauth2 profile**

My first thought was to try the oauth2 playground and see if this information was returned by a profile call

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
```

It was note.  That would have been to easy

**People API**

Then I thought i would try was [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me
```

There is a lot of information here but not about what day i created my account.

**Calendar**

This lead me to think that a calendar is also created the primary calendar in google calendar when you create your account [calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary
```

This didnt work either there is no create date.

**Drive**

Then I remembered that your root drive in Google drive is also created when you create your account. [try this](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.get?fileId=root&fields=*&_h=4&)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/root?fields=*&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

> "createdTime": "2009-01-30T15:52:51.516Z",

**Answer**: the only way i can see currently to find out when a user created their google account is to check the createdtime on the root directory in Google Drive.   That being said i would have thought my account was older than that but i am still looking.

Comment: anyway, accessing google drive user account will require the user to approve your organization to have access to the user's google drive account. Not sure all your visitors will be pleased with that

Comment: found another thing recently you can do a binary search to find your earliest email mine was late 2007 so this is not actuate.

Comment: @DaImTo is there any reference link?

Comment: @DaImTo can find first received email

Comment: @DaImTo I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049234/gmail-api-fastest-way-to-get-the-oldest-email-in-inbox

Comment: yup that's the one.

Comment: If Drive is not accessed after Google account creation, the "createdTime" is not accurate. I'm telling this because I'm absolutely sure that my own account was created much earlier than what I saw using that api.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think tis is only for Google drive, which so far as I know didn't exist when gmail was created.
My gmail account was created in like 2000 when gmail was still in beta, but that API gives me 2008.