# GMail API: Fastest way to get the oldest email in inbox

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I want to get the oldest email in GMail inbox. How can I do that with the minimum number of API calls?

One way to do it could be to get the total number of emails from `Users:getProfile` API and then use `User.messages:list` API to get the last page using "**pageToken**" query parameter by using the formula

> pageToken = totalMessages/50

to get the list of messages from the last page of my inbox and then using the `mid` of the last message in the list to fetch the oldest email.

I am just wondering if there is a better way to do this? I could not figure out other ways to do it from the documentation. Any search filter that will fetch me the oldest email?

Answer (score 2):

[User.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) contains a paramter called q which can be used for searching.

> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messagesq=before%3A2008%2F01%2F01&access_token={token}

Basicly `before:2008/01/01` is sent just like searching in the gmail web app return all the emails before that date.

The trick here will be narrowing down your search.  Gmail was released on 2004.  Which gives yo possible start between 2018 and 2004 split it in half

```
before:2011/01/01  (there were mails split it in half again) 
before:2007/01/01  (there were no mails must be between 11 and 7)
before:2009/01/01  (...)
```

There is a term for this method of searching but i cant remember it right now.  Basically you keep dividing it by two and finding out where the result must be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer DalmTo. Binary search is the term you're looking for.  I thought about using the q param to apply "before" or "older" search filter. Strangely, there is no search filter to sort emails by oldest first. 

But by using your algorithm, I might need to make a lot of API calls to find the oldest email. I was looking for a faster way to do this. I guess there is no other way.

Comment: Binary search! thats the one.   I feel your pain about the lack of sorting I have wished for that ability for years.  This is the only way i know of.

Comment: BTW very few of the Google APIs support sorting they expect the developers to do it themselves locally after they return the response